# Chart For Special Time During A Day

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, nevron

I'm trying to draw a chart for a collection of DateTime(x) -> Double(y).

Dates are between 8:00 AM and 2:00 PM, so I want to see this duration in the chart, remove 2:00 PM to 8:00 AM for every Date, like this (Date is converted in this picture (wrong Date):

[image]

Correct date:

[image]

I tried to draw this with Nevron Chart, but I couldn't.

Does anyone who knows how to do this especially with **Nevron** or any other chart? Which chart component provides this feature?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the Nevron Chart Daily Schedule Work Calendar example. The example demonstrates how to use the daily schedule of the work calendar in order to skip hourly ranges for which there is no data.

```
    // create a timeline scale
    NRangeTimelineScaleConfigurator rangeScale  = new NRangeTimelineScaleConfigurator();
    rangeScale.EnableCalendar = true;

    // create a rule
    NWeekDayRule wdr = new NWeekDayRule();
    wdr.Saturday = false;
    wdr.Sunday = false;

    // set shedule non working hours
    wdr.Schedule.SetHourRange(0, 9, true);
    wdr.Schedule.SetHourRange(12, 13, true);
    wdr.Schedule.SetHourRange(18, 24, true);

    rangeScale.Calendar.Rules.Add(wdr);
```

Comment: It's usually requested to post a summary of the advice in the answer. A link (not that you've provided one) is generally not accepted, but instead a small code snippet or similar would be useful.